# Taskbar menu like Start menu, search bar, Windows Defender etc won't respond on clicking

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, start-menu

Start menu, search option, windows defender are not responding on click. Defender gets opened and then closes.

I have tried -

Restarting windows explorer from task manager.
Created other user profile.
Checked safe mode. Same issue there
Changed value of start under local machine which is under regedit.
I can't reset this pc as my work apps are installed and I don't remember my username and password to login again if I remove them. So, looking for an alternative. Even I tried signing in Microsoft account through settings, it opens and then closes. Please suggest.

Comment: What does Event Viewer say? What repair methods have you tried? Windows repair methods are well documented and you should try them for this sort of issue.

Answer (score 0):

> Start menu, search option, windows defender are not responding on
> click. Defender gets opened and then closes.  ........    Created
> other user profile.

Since this issue is not the Windows User Profile, try a Windows 10 Repair Install.

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

> Windows 10/11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally
> answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.
>
> This will likely work.  If not, same process and (a) Keep Data (and
> User Profile) but reinstall Software;  and (b) Keep Nothing (back up
> first and Keep Nothing reinstalls Windows).